# Converting of Lead Error

Tags: leads, standard-objects, lead-conversion

The error below occur if I'm converting a lead that has the same account in Lead Conversion. For example,

I put a Lead under the Account 1 then convert it also with Account 1. Is this possible in Salesforce OOTB or does the Salesforce thinks that it parents itself (Account) so that it shown an error of **CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY**? What is the other recommendation to solve this error? Thank you.

> Error: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0
>   with id 0010n000001oXhvAAE; first error: CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY, attempt
>   to violate hierarchy constraints: [Hotel__c]
>   Class.leadconvert.BulkLeadConvert.handleRegularAccountUpdates: line
>   261, column 1 Class.leadconvert.BulkLeadConvert.convertLead: line 92,
>   column 1

Comment: are you converting from UI or you have written a code for lead conversion?

Comment: from the UI only @SantanuBoral

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The post should be re-posted as a question.

Answer (score 0):

You are right It seems you are trying to create a circular dependency and the same is not allowed in salesforce, say for example  :-

you are trying to create a circular account hierarchy : -

For Example:       Account 1's parent is Account 2,
Account 2 parent is Account 3
and then you are trying to set Account 3 parent to be Account 1

it will be not possible in salesforce.

Comment: So whenever I convert a lead in an account, the converted account will be the child of the the lead in an account? Am I right? @Avijit Das